# xcode isn't displaying source control icons anymore

Tags: xcode, macos, git

Here's a crazy one...

XCode isn't displaying the source control icons in the project navigator anymore. I've been using git for a while now (not to mention successfully in my current project for 3 years). For whatever reason, those little M, A, ?, etc... icons aren't showing up anymore. More annoying is that the version browser doesn't work at all now.

Have any of you by chance had this happen and figured it out?

Comment: You didn't accidentally delete the .git folder (which is hidden by default)?

Comment: Go in your project directory in the Terminal, and type `git status` to see what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iMac:myAppName crewshin$ git status
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/origin/master (MBP.home's conflicted copy 2013-01-20)'
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule myAppName/Libraries/FMDB

Something got corrupted in a submodule. No idea why but I removed it and re-cloned my repo. All good now. Thanks guys.